# How can I horizontally align an image created with psmatrix?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, pstricks

I've got an image created with `psmatrix` code and I would like to put it at 1/4 of the text width. Using `\centering` in the image environment it gets too far to the right.

I'm sorry but my code is a mess ;)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[showframe=true]{geometry}

\begin{document}
 \begin{figure}[htbp] 
\psscalebox{1}{
$
  \begin{psmatrix}[framesep=5pt,colsep=2cm]
      & \psframebox[]{SET~T_1} \\
        \psframebox[]{SET~T_2} & \psframebox[]{IMT}\\
       & \psframebox[]{SEM}
     \psset{arrows=->,nodesep=5pt}
      \ncline{1,2}{2,2}
      \naput{\textit{flusso di energia chimica}}\nbput{\begin{minipage}{1.5cm}\begin{center}\boldmath{$\dot{m}_cH_i$ }\end{center}\end{minipage}}
        \ncline{2,2}{2,1}\nbput{\textit{perdite}}
      \ncline{2,2}{3,2}
      \naput{\textit{potenza meccanica utile all'asse}}\nbput{\begin{minipage}       {1.5cm}\begin{center}\boldmath{$P_u$ }\end{center}\end{minipage}}
  \end{psmatrix}
     $}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: You can try `\hspace*{0.25\linewidth}`

Comment: You could get 1/4 centering to the left using: `\noindent\leavevmode\hbox to \linewidth{\hss\hbox{<psmatrix code>}\hss\hss\hss}`, but maybe a more high-level way would be better.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: I think using `\makebox` is more elegant.

Answer (score 3):

I will try to answer this question.

*Sidenote:*
You MWE is too long. You loaded packages which aren't related to your question. Please avid this.

*End Sidenote*

The width of the environment `psmatrix` based on the contents. To start the environment `0.25\textwidth` of the left margin you can simple use `\hspace*{0.25\linewidth}`. That is shown in the example below. The next option (also shown) you can use the command `\makebox` with the following syntax:

```
\makebox[<width>][<inner alignment>]{<content>}
```

With the command `\makebox` you can align the environment at the center.

The package `adjustbox` provides more possibilities.

To demonstrate the result I used the option `showframe`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=2.0cm,right=2.0cm,heightrounded,bindingoffset=5mm}
\geometry{showframe}
\begin{document}
 \begin{figure}[htbp] 
\hspace*{0.25\linewidth}%
\makebox[0pt][c]{\psscalebox{1}{
$%
  \begin{psmatrix}[framesep=5pt,colsep=2cm]
      & \psframebox[]{SET~T_1} \\
        \psframebox[]{SET~T_2} & \psframebox[]{IMT}\\
       & \psframebox[]{SEM}
     \psset{arrows=->,nodesep=5pt}
      \ncline{1,2}{2,2}
      \naput{\textit{flusso di energia chimica}}\nbput{\begin{minipage}{1.5cm}\begin{center}\boldmath{$\dot{m}_cH_i$ }\end{center}\end{minipage}}
        \ncline{2,2}{2,1}\nbput{\textit{perdite}}
      \ncline{2,2}{3,2}
      \naput{\textit{potenza meccanica utile all'asse}}\nbput{\begin{minipage}       {1.5cm}\begin{center}\boldmath{$P_u$ }\end{center}\end{minipage}}
  \end{psmatrix}
     $}}
 \end{figure}
  \begin{figure}[htbp] 
\hspace*{0.25\linewidth}%
 \psscalebox{1}{
$%
  \begin{psmatrix}[framesep=5pt,colsep=2cm]
      & \psframebox[]{SET~T_1} \\
        \psframebox[]{SET~T_2} & \psframebox[]{IMT}\\
       & \psframebox[]{SEM}
     \psset{arrows=->,nodesep=5pt}
      \ncline{1,2}{2,2}
      \naput{\textit{flusso di energia chimica}}\nbput{\begin{minipage}{1.5cm}\begin{center}\boldmath{$\dot{m}_cH_i$ }\end{center}\end{minipage}}
        \ncline{2,2}{2,1}\nbput{\textit{perdite}}
      \ncline{2,2}{3,2}
      \naput{\textit{potenza meccanica utile all'asse}}\nbput{\begin{minipage}       {1.5cm}\begin{center}\boldmath{$P_u$ }\end{center}\end{minipage}}
  \end{psmatrix}
     $}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]